# How to download a specific date EXCEL under several pull down menus from web page?

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas, export-to-csv

How to download the file under [Hang seng index and sub index] pull down list 1;[index daily bulletin] pull down list 2; [a specific date/Friday] pull down list ?
Also, how to repeat for the previous 10 Fridays?
Here is the link "https://www.hsi.com.hk/eng/resources-education/daily-reports"

Comment: using library selenium

Comment: And more easy , the url has a parameters 
https://www.hsi.com.hk/static/uploads/contents/en/indexes/report/hsi/idx_18Oct19.csv
https://www.hsi.com.hk/static/uploads/contents/en/indexes/report/hsi/idx_25Oct19.csv
https://www.hsi.com.hk/static/uploads/contents/en/indexes/report/hsi/idx_1Nov19.csv
https://www.hsi.com.hk/static/uploads/contents/en/indexes/report/hsi/idx_8Nov19.csv
....
..